# Get all buttons with an assigned ToolTip

Tags: c#, .net, controls, tooltip

I want to get all buttons that have assigned ToolTip in the designer. I tried to do this using reflection but to add ToolTip to a buttons I added a ToolTip control to my form. Now all buttons have a property in designer called `ToolTip on myToolTipControlName`

`obj` is my button object and this code:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

does not have a property called ToolTip and so on.

So how can I get this ToolTip text of a button? I need this text to translate mechanism to another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `t1` is your tooltip object then `t1.GetTooltip(obj)` will return the text for it.